# Apps Script Error - Cannot find method getRange(number,number,(class),number)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a custom Google Apps Script that will pull some data (2 columns wide, 50-100 rows long but this varies)in an array 2  from an API, parse it into JSON and then paste into a google sheet.

I can run the script from the editor and it works ok. But when I try to run it from a custom menu or when I run the debugger I get the following error:

'Cannot find method getRange(number,number,(class),number) (line 43)'

Line 43 is the last line of the code.

```
sheet.getRange(3,1,dataSet.length,2).setValues(rows);
```

It seems that the issue is that getRange is not able to use the variable of length of the dataset (number of rows) to set the number of rows to use in the range in which the data is to be pasted.

I cannot work out how to fix this - can anyone else see what I am doing wrong? Thanks for taking a look.

```
//custom menu
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('XXXX Data')
      .addItem('Credit Limits','CREDITLIMITS')
      .addToUi();
}

function CREDITLIMITS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get active spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data'); //get sheet by name from active spreadsheet


  // URL and params for the API
  var USERNAME = 'XXXXXXX';
  var PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var url = 'https://api.XXXX.com/api/v1/XXX/?where=type=%27XXXXXXX%27';  //   var url="http://example.com/feeds?type=json"; // Paste your JSON URL here
  var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);  
  var params = {'method': 'GET','muteHttpExceptions': true,'headers': {'Authorization': authHeader,} };

  //call the XXXX API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params); // get api endpoint
  var json = response.getContentText(); // get the response content as text
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(json); //parse text into json
  var dataSet = dataAll;

//create empty array to hold data points
var rows=[],
data; 

//loop over the retrun events
  for (i=0; i < dataSet.length; i++)  {
   data = dataSet[i];
//push a row of data as 2d array   
    rows.push([data.company, data.creditLimit]);
  }

// clear any previous content
    sheet.getRange(1,1,500,10).clearContent();

// write data to sheet
   sheet.getRange(3,1,dataSet.length,2).setValues(rows);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `row.length`?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems the error is trying to tell you that you can't call method getRange using a class variable (as opposed to number). 

Try storing dataSet.length in it's own variable and passing that to the method.

Comment: Where is your log of what `dataSet`and `dataSet.length` are when the error occurs? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Comment: Perhaps you didn't get a response from your URLFetch.

Comment: Did you work out a solution to your problem, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies - much appreciated. I am still workinng on this and have no solution yet.

Comment: @tehhowch The log shows that dataSet.length is 50.0 and dataSet is the 50 pairs of data in as requested. See log below

[19-03-06 14:51:03:875 GMT] 2019-03-06 14:51:03:875 +0000 002717 INFO dataSet.length = 50
[19-03-06 14:51:03:989 GMT] 2019-03-06 14:51:03:989 +0000 002831 INFO dataSet = [object Object],xxxx,[object Object]

where xxxx is the 48 other pairs [object Object],

Comment: @a-burge I did try to store 'dataSet.length in it's own variable and passing that to the method' but this made no difference.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your reply - I am still looking for help yes.

Comment: Edit your question. You create `dataSet` by parsing JSON. So where is your example of this object in your question? Show it's structure. Show what `typeof` provides for `dataSet`, `dataSet.length`, what `Array.isArray` says, etc. Since you do not provide an MCVE we cannot reproduce, we can only say your problem is with `dataSet` and `dataSet.length`

Comment: have you tried the debugging function to see what dataset.length is when it is passed to the getRange()?